# Beginner Python 3.3.2 - How do I use .replace() from a file?

Tags: file, python-3.x, replace

Let's say I have a .txt file that contains the following information:

```
a g
b j
d l
e o
q p
```

How do I make a program that asks the user for input (a string) and swaps the first letter with the corresponding letter next to it. Example output:

```
Enter string: Jelly bean queen
Swapped: Joddy jogn puoon
```

My code so far is this:

```
input1 = input("Enter string: ")
a1 = "" #A1 refers to the first column of letters
a2 = "" #A2 refers to the second column of letters
with open("text_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a1 = a1 + line[0] #Adds the first letters to A1
        a2 = a2 + line[2] #Adds the second letter to A2
```

I tried lots of things after that but none seemed to work, most of my attempts don't make any sense. I'd ask my tutor for help but they are all busy and I don't want to bother them anymore lol. Sorry for my newbieness. If anyone needs further clarification just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to transform `a1` and `a2` into a translation table, which can then be used with [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
translation_table = str.maketrans(a1, a2)
swapped = input1.translate(translation_table)
```

Comment: Interesting proposition. I've never heard of a translation table and I'll read up on that now. *EDIT* Yup that solved my problem thanks, will bookmark that documentation url.